# How I can create a list with images and more than one line in onsen-ui?

Tags: onsen-ui

I am looking at the documentation of onsenui as generate a list like the one shown in this picture: http://onsenui.io/images/index/feature-custom-elements.png

But I could only generate a simple list with only one row for each item, anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is listed on this page. You can learn how to create the UI with Onsen UI by referencing the page.

http://components.onsenui.io/

[image: Onsen CSS Components]